# Show heap status in Domino Designer resets every time

Tags: heap-memory, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

Is there a way to make this setting stick?
Everytime I enter Domino Designer I need to enable this setting under Preferences-General.
It is set but the heap status is not shown. Need to disable and enable again.
Frustrating...

Version 8.5.3 or ND9, same "error"

Comment: What version of Designer are you using?

Comment: `SPR #GGRD94DP45` - Got this from **[here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndsebetaforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=AE9A1CAE5A46A40285257ADB00613631)**. This occurs even in 8.5.3 and drives me crazy! And its still not fixed in Notes 9 :(

Comment: Must be a setting in some prefs file somewhere but I can't seem to find it. I'll test with a pure Eclipse and see what gets set/changed.

Comment: Did not find anything useful…